# Encoding/locale of gitlab runner machine

Tags: msbuild, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup GitLab runner on winserver 2016.

Everything works fine, except output of runner on gitlab.

Locale of winserver is RU.

I'm trying to build projects with MSBUILD, which outputs russian characters:

`Checking out e5ec41d1 as release-2...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "начинается  билд %PROJECT_NAME%"
"начинается  билд PEPSolution"
$ echo "Релизная сборка... "
"Релизная сборка... "
$ "C:\Program Files ^(x86^)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Release /verbosity:quiet "%PROJECT_NAME%.sln"
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2398,5): error MSB3091: ������ �� �믮�����, ⠪ ��� �� �����㦥�`

Russian symbols from `yml` file are displayed correctly. But from output of MSBUILD is wrong

So questions are:

1. How to make it to show in correctly?
2. May be I violate some best practices?

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add before "stages:" command "- CHCP 65001" in "before_script:"

```
before_script:
  - CHCP 65001

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Found finaly solution!

just add

`- chcp 65001`

into yml file before calling msbuild

it tells change default codepage of cmd to utf8

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue (Windows 10 Home for one language - russian, v.1903, build 18362.535).
Result of gitlab runner:

```
 1 Running with gitlab-runner 12.6.0 (ac8e767a)
 2   on gitlab-unity-runner vzC5L735
 3 Using Shell executor...
 4 Running on DESKTOP-LOSJ2JN...
 5 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 6 & : ��� "git" �� ��ᯮ����� ��� ��� ����������, �㭪樨, 䠩�� �業���� ��� �믮��塞�� �ணࠬ��. �஢����� �ࠢ��쭮�
 7 �� ����ᠭ�� �����, � ⠪�� ����稥 � �ࠢ��쭮��� ����, ��᫥ 祣� ��������� �������.
 8 C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script960183957\script.ps1:163 ����:3
 9 + & "git" "config" "-f" "C:\<user>\GitLab-Runner\builds\vzC5L735\0\ga ...
10 +   ~~~~~
11     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
12     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
13  
14 cd : �� 㤠���� ����� ���� "C:\<user>\GitLab-Runner\builds\vzC5L735\0\<user>\test_unity_ci_project", ⠪ ��� �� �� 
15 ����������.
16 C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script063808752\script.ps1:159 ����:1
17 + cd "C:\<user>\GitLab-Runner\builds\vzC5L735\0\<user>\test_unity_c ...
18 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
19     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\<user>\Git...nity_ci_project:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE 
20    xception
21     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
22  
23 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I've set language for non unicode programs:
Control panel -> Regional standards -> Additional -> Language for non unicode programs -> Change system language -> change to 'English (USA)' -> reboot.

**scr1**

[image]

**scr2**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XePuw.png]

After that I've got correct gitlab runner message:

```
 1 Running with gitlab-runner 12.6.0 (ac8e767a)
 2   on gitlab-unity-runner vzC5L735
 3 Using Shell executor...
 5 Running on DESKTOP-LOSJ2JN...
 7 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 8 & : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spe
 9 lling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
10 At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script179741393\script.ps1:163 char:3
11 + & "git" "config" "-f" "C:\<user>\GitLab-Runner\builds\vzC5L735\0\ga ...
12 +   ~~~~~
13     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
14     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
15  
17 cd : Cannot find path 'C:\<user>\GitLab-Runner\builds\vzC5L735\0\<user>\test_unity_ci_project' because it does not 
18 exist.
19 At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script677283324\script.ps1:159 char:1
20 + cd "C:\<user>\GitLab-Runner\builds\vzC5L735\0\<user>\test_unity_c ...
21 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
22     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\<user>\Git...nity_ci_project:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE 
23    xception
24     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
25  
27 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: It's useless. If I want to use Cyrillic symbols, it doesn't help at all.

Comment: got it, @noisy88, all my next comments I will first approve with you

Comment: sure, if it will help you.